# Why use sequelize-typescript while sequelize provides its own types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I don't understand why should we use sequelize-typescript over sequelize ?
I didn't find any references answer it except the fact sequelize-typescript provides me "decorators"

on their [official documentation](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#readme)  was written "Decorators and some other features for sequelize (v5)."
But what are those "other features"

Comment: Did you try looking inside both libraries' type definitions - acutally opening the d.ts files - and seeing what's inside? It could be that the maintainers split typings into two packages or something